# AVL tracking system database

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, gps

i am new DBA in a company using a tracking system for up than 1K device , and update for every 10 sec

the database is Postgresql v11 , but when we do some query it take time , 
is postgresql qualify for this kind of heavy duty ?? or should we move to sql server ?? 
is there any technic will enhance the performance ?? 
or should i start with the query ??

```
-- View: public.api_devicelist_v2

-- DROP VIEW public.api_devicelist_v2;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.api_devicelist_v2 AS
SELECT COALESCE(tc_positions.attributes -> 'c_door'::text, '0'::jsonb)::integer AS door_icon,
        CASE
            WHEN age(now(), tc_positions.fixtime::timestamp with time zone) > '01:00:00'::interval AND tc_positions.speed > 0::double precision THEN 5
            WHEN age(now(), tc_positions.fixtime::timestamp with time zone) > '01:00:00'::interval AND tc_positions.speed = 0::double precision THEN 6
            WHEN tc_positions.fixtime IS NULL THEN 7
            WHEN COALESCE(tc_positions.attributes -> 'c_ign'::text, '0'::jsonb) = '0'::jsonb AND tc_positions.speed > 0::double precision THEN 1
            WHEN COALESCE(tc_positions.attributes -> 'c_ign'::text, '0'::jsonb) = '1'::jsonb AND tc_positions.speed > 0::double precision THEN 2
            WHEN COALESCE(tc_positions.attributes -> 'c_ign'::text, '0'::jsonb) = '0'::jsonb AND tc_positions.speed = 0::double precision THEN 3
            WHEN COALESCE(tc_positions.attributes -> 'c_ign'::text, '0'::jsonb) = '1'::jsonb AND tc_positions.speed = 0::double precision THEN 4
            ELSE 0
        END AS icon_motion,
    tc_devices.id,
    tc_devices.name,
    date_part('epoch'::text, timezone('utc'::text, tc_positions.servertime))::integer AS servertime,
    date_part('epoch'::text, timezone('utc'::text, tc_positions.fixtime))::integer AS fixtime,
    COALESCE(tc_positions.latitude, '0'::double precision) AS latitude,
    COALESCE(tc_positions.longitude, '0'::double precision) AS longitude,
    COALESCE(tc_positions.speed, '0'::double precision) AS speed,
    COALESCE(tc_positions.course, '0'::double precision) AS course,
    COALESCE(tc_positions.attributes -> 'c_ign'::text, '0'::jsonb) AS engine,
    COALESCE(tc_positions.attributes -> 'c_door'::text, '0'::jsonb) AS door,
    COALESCE(tc_positions.attributes -> 'c_doorMove'::text, '0'::jsonb) AS door_move,
    COALESCE(tc_positions.attributes -> 'c_ls_door'::text, 'false'::jsonb) AS prev_door,
    COALESCE(tc_positions.attributes -> 'c_ls_ign'::text, 'false'::jsonb) AS prev_engine,
    COALESCE(tc_positions.valid, false) AS valid,
    tc_devices.type,
    tc_devices.uniqueid
   FROM tc_devices
     JOIN tc_positions ON tc_devices.positionid = tc_positions.id
  WHERE tc_devices.positionid IS NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE public.api_devicelist_v2
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

[query1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T664y.png)

Query 2

```
SELECT id, protocol, deviceid, servertime, devicetime, fixtime, valid, latitude, longitude, altitude, speed, course, address, attributes2, accuracy, network, attributes
                FROM public.tc_positions where deviceid=98743
                order by id desc limit 1
```

But it take a long to excute for this simple query  maybe locking ???

[query2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4bFn.png)

```
SELECT id, protocol, deviceid, servertime, devicetime, fixtime, valid, latitude, longitude, altitude, speed, course, address, attributes2, accuracy, network, attributes
                FROM public.tc_positions where deviceid=98743


       and fixtime between '2019-05-05 14:08:22' and '2019-09-06 14:08:22'
```

[query3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur9GG.png)

table ::

```
-- Table: public.tc_positions

CREATE TABLE public.tc_positions
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tc_positionsne_id_seq'::regclass),
    protocol character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    deviceid integer NOT NULL,
    servertime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    devicetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    fixtime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    valid boolean NOT NULL,
    latitude double precision NOT NULL,
    longitude double precision NOT NULL,
    altitude double precision NOT NULL,
    speed double precision NOT NULL,
    course double precision NOT NULL,
    address character varying(512) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    attributes2 character varying(4000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    accuracy double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    network character varying(4000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    attributes jsonb,
    CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_positions_deviceid FOREIGN KEY (deviceid)
        REFERENCES public.tc_devices (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.tc_positions
    OWNER to postgres;

-- Index: device_id_id

CREATE INDEX device_id_id
    ON public.tc_positions USING btree
    (id DESC, deviceid)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.tc_positions
    CLUSTER ON device_id_id;

-- Index: device_id_idx2

CREATE INDEX device_id_idx2
    ON public.tc_positions USING btree
    (id)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: deviceid_fixtime

CREATE INDEX deviceid_fixtime
    ON public.tc_positions USING btree
    (deviceid, fixtime)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: devicevalidtime2

CREATE INDEX devicevalidtime2
    ON public.tc_positions USING btree
    (deviceid, devicetime, valid)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: fixture

CREATE INDEX fixture
    ON public.tc_positions USING btree
    (fixtime, deviceid, valid)
    INCLUDE(valid)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: tc_positions_devicetime_idx2

-- DROP INDEX public.tc_positions_devicetime_idx2;

CREATE INDEX tc_positions_devicetime_idx2
    ON public.tc_positions USING btree
    (devicetime DESC)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

thank you

Comment: Could you include planning, execution time and total time with the query analyzis ?

Comment: the planning have been added in the link of each query .

Comment: Well - I can't see the planning/execution/total time.  Should be at the bottom when you run explain analyze.  I'm sure the queries and indices can be improved but I'm rather inclined to suggest you look at NoSql databases for this sort of data.  Postgres is a transactional database (Mssql too) and they are perhaps not the best tools.

Answer (score 0):

You need an index on `tc_devices.positionid` to improve the performance of Query 1.